# AngularJS 1.2.x: Change in decoding URL in routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to migrate my application from AngularJS 1.0.8 to 1.2.14 and it seems like there is some "new" URL decoding in 1.2.

I have following routing:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/title/:simpleName/:simpleVersion', {templateUrl: 'partials/public/view/spec.html', controller: SpecificationCtrl});
 $routeProvider.when('/title/:simpleName', {redirectTo: '/title/:simpleName/latest'});
```

And in one of my directives, I'm creating anchors like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
   elem.html('<a href="#/title/' + encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(simpleName)) + '/">...</a>')
}
```

where `simpleName` can be some string like `x/y++_test`.

In Angular 1.0.8, if user clicks on such link, browser contains following URL:

```
.../title/x%252Fy%252B%252B_test
```

and everything works fine. But with Angular 1.2, browser for a second contains again the escaped form and then **URL in browser changes** to

```
.../title/x/y++_test
```

which is problem as it may not match my routing rules and routing parameters. When this change happens, according to Chrome Dev Tools, the page as such is not reloaded and controllers are created just once when the totally decoded URL is displayed.

Is there some new change that causes? How could I make it working the same way as in 1.0.8 ? I've searched Angular's changelog but haven't found any mention  of url decoding.

**Update**:
I've created to Plunks with Angular 1.0.8 and 1.2.13 to demonstrate the issue (the only difference is that the link is hardcoded in HTML code instead of being generated by directive). Simply click on "here" link in the plunk and watch the displayed URL:

- [Plunk with Angular 1.0.8](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQUFclZHkJIUgMnKMbLx?p=preview)
- [Plunk with Angular 1.2.13](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz4K9ElK6cW22ABV0M6E?p=info)

Comment: I have a similar problem. Seems it's a bug in Angular, here's an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5645. Haven't found a workaround yet.

Comment: Thank you for link, I added my comment. If it's the same, I do consider it a bug :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a ng-href="#/title/{{encodeURIComponent(simpleName)}}">...</a>
```

And inside the controller in case you haven't done it:

```
$scope.encodeURIComponent = encodeURIComponent;
```

Comment: Thank, but that won't help. The ````a```` element is created in directove's link() function and it is correctly inserted in HTML code. The problem is that if I click on the link, URL for a very brief moment contains the escaped form (that's expected) but then it changes to the decoded form. It is interesting since I encoded it twice and yet it is fully decoded...

Comment: Can you post a plunkr?

Comment: From what I've seen, it looks like it does a decodeURI after the route  is matched. Does it really causes you any issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, check the route rule above, it contains 2 parameters and this decoding causes that part of the 1st parameter is considered to be the 2nd parameter.